# Strange lighting bug in my game

Tags: lighting, shadows, fog

I've been experiencing this lighting bug in my game.

[image: bug]

As you can see there is a box around the player on the back wall and underneath it. the platform and back wall are 3D objects and the player is a 2D sprite. i believe i have found an option in the past but i am unable to find where it is now. I really appreciate you help and thank you all in advance

Comment: I was having this issue, but I need more information.
Is this unity?, are u using multiple render cameras?
If ur are using canvas play a little bit with the pixes per unit. (This is what solved my problem).

Comment: Yes this is unity, no that is the only render camera. I am using a canvas so i'll try that thank you